# Make cursor not move out of the div element when tab key is pressed

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a search input box where I allow user to either enter value or provide list of suggestions from where user can select an entry. User can use tab key in order to select the suggested entry from the list. The issue is when user selects the option using tab key, the cursor moves outside the input box. When I select the option using mouse, the cursor stays in the input box.

My code looks like:

```
<SearchBar 
  <SearchInputWrapper>
    <SearchInputBox>
      <TextInput
                          placeholder="Enter Text here"
                          minHeight="17px"
                          setSearchText={handleTextChange}
                          paddingTopBottom="5px"
                          paddingLeftRight="4px"
                          lineHeight="1.2"/>
    </SearchInputBox>
  </SearchInputWrapper>
/>

const SearchInputWrapper = styled.div`
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  align-self: stretch;
  word-break: break-word;
 
  #tags-container:not(:focus) {
    height: 20px;
    text-overflow: ${({ pinned }) => (pinned ? 'unset' : 'ellipsis')};
    white-space: ${({ pinned }) => (pinned ? 'unset' : 'nowrap')};
  }

  #tags-container:focus {
    height: 20px;
    text-overflow: unset;
    white-space: unset;
    word-break: normal;
  }
`;
```

TextInput is a custom component which already has keyDown being taken care of:

```
class TextInput extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);
 }
const TAB = 9;
handleKeyDown(event) {
if (
      event.which === TAB ||
      (event.which === ENTER && meta) ||
      (event.which === SPACE && meta)
    ) {
      this.suggestionsList.apply();
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
    } 
}
}
```

But the keyDown is being overridden by the callBack function(handleTextChange). Can I pass event in the callBack function that is overriding it and add e.stopPropogation in there ? I tried to add a workaround and added document.getElementsById("#id").focus() in the below function. It retains the focus but the cursor always stays at the start of the text input. I would like it to always be present in the end of the text in the textbox.

```
const handleTextChange = useCallback(
    (q) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
      updateModel({
        ...model,
        searchText: q
          }
        }
      });
     document.getElementById('input-textbox').focus();
    },
    [updateModel, model]
  );
```

[image]
How do I make the cursor stay in the input box on tab key selection such that the after the textbox displays the selected value the cursor stay at the end of the text?

Comment: it will be great help if you will create a fiddle/demo of your code which is generating the error. Thank you

Comment: I don't know why you wanted ```Tab key``` to select suggestions...Instead you could have used ```Arrow Up``` and ```Arrow Down```. ```Tab``` key will go to the next element adjcent to your current one, this is the default behaviour.

Comment: I believe that the behaviour Mallikarjun describes is the canonical behaviour and that you will need javascript answers like below if you want your own custom solution

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex
i guess this is what you are looking for

Comment: Where is `TextInput` coming from?

Answer (score 1):

You need behaviour within `event.preventDefault()`, something like:

```
<TextInput
  placeholder="Enter Text here"
  minHeight="17px"
  paddingTopBottom="5px"
  paddingLeftRight="4px"
  lineHeight="1.2"
  onKeyDown={(event) => {
    if (event.key === "Tab") {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }}
/>
```

You need to check if the `pressed key` is the `tab key` within add an `onKeyDown` event listener to the `TextInput` component

Comment: How this will solve the answer? user wants to hold the cursor inside the input element but not to bind tab key?

Comment: This doesn't work :( event.preventDefault has already been applied! Inspite of that this behavior exists